# Warum ist „Kleinvieh macht auch Mist" positiv gemeint?

Tags: idiom

Wieso wird *Kleinvieh macht auch Mist* positiv verstanden (z.B. [auch kleine Gewinne bringen Nutzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kleinvieh_macht_auch_Mist))? Der Vergleich „kleiner (quasi infinitesimalen) Einheiten die ein Ganzes ergeben“ scheint wegen *Mist* eher ursprünglich in einem „negativen Bereich“ zu erfolgen.

Wenn sich ein Muttersprachler zum ersten Mal diese Redewendung anhört--sagen wir mal, er oder sie fängt an, sich eine Person am Telefon anzuhören (die mit einem dritten spricht)--denkt er oder sie automatisch an eine positive Konnotation? Oder sind da ein Kontext und Vertrautheit fällig?

**Bearbeitet**: Nach guidots Antwort würde stellt sich heraus, dass meine Annahme *Mist* sei negativ falsch war. Die Frage nach dem ersten Effekt vom Satz auf Muttersprachler würde mich noch interessieren.

Comment: Ich fürchte, dass das "wieso" Dir keiner erklären kann... Tatsache ist: dieses Sprichwort habe ich (Muttersprachler) noch nie in einer negativen Konnotation gehört: Es ist immer positiv belegt...

Comment: Ich habe gerade nicht die Zeit, das genauer auszuarbeiten, aber ich finde den Ansatz, dass es eine alte Gleichsetzung von Geld und Fäkalien gebe. Siehe z. B. [wissenschaft-im-dialog.de](https://www.wissenschaft-im-dialog.de/projekte/wieso/artikel/beitrag/woher-stammt-die-redewendung-kleinvieh-macht-auch-mist/): "Die Gleichsetzung von Geld = Mist = Fäkalien (“Scheiße“) usw. ist in den Volksüberlieferungen in zahlreichen Redewendungen und verschiedenen Bedeutungen zu finden."

Comment: Einen ähnlichen Ansatz hat offenbar Siegmund Freud verfolgt, siehe z. B. [diesen taz-Artikel](https://taz.de/Der-Furz-der-Inflation/!1355024/): "(...) aber er hatte, angeregt durch Märchen, Aberglauben und Folklore und natürlich auch die Einfälle seiner Patienten, erkannt, daß die Menschen unbewußt Kot und Geld gleichsetzen, zum Beispiel in der Figur des Dukatenscheißers. Daraus schloß er, daß das Geld ein Kotsymbol sei." Vielleicht hat jemand Zeit und Lust, aus diesem Ansatz eine Antwort zu machen.

Comment: @TorstenLink Das glaube ich dir. Was ich auch gerne wüste ist, ob ohne dass du den Satz immer positiv belegt gehört hast, würdest du anfangen, dem eine positive Konnotation zuzuordnen.

Comment: Die Quellenlage über die Entstehung von Redewendungen ist unbefriedigend, denn bevor eine Redewendung in den Sprachschatz aufgenommen wird, muss sie sich bereits durchgesetzt haben. Es wird da nach Kräften spekuliert. _'Mist'_ ist im landwirtschaftlichen Kontext etwas Positives, weil es guter Dünger ist. Aber Mist stinkt auch, was unangenehm ist, außerdem kann man ('wertlosen') Bio'müll' auf den Misthaufen werfen. Ich hatte als kleiner Junge die Redewendung nicht sofort verstanden, das mit dem betonten 'auch' und mit Bezug auf '**Klein**(vieh)' gibt dem Satz eine unerwartete Wendung.

Comment: Es hilft sehr, sich generell von dem Versuch loszusagen, Wörter und Wendungen in positive und negative aufzuteilen. Es ist einfach fast immer falsch und man führt sich nur selbst an der Nase herum. Die Semantik ist ganz prinzipiell etwas anderes, als eine Bewertung. Beispiel: "Die Bank hat mir wieder 60 ¢ für einen Kontoauszug abgeknöpft!" A: "Ja, Kleinvieh macht auch Mist." Semantisch ist das die gleiche Wendung, nur ist derjenige, der den Mist bekommt, ein anderer. Die Bewertung IST negativ. Ist aber wohl wieder vergebene Liebesmüh, das publik machen zu wollen.

Answer (score 10):

Tatsächlich hat *Mist* sowohl ein positive Bedeutung als auch eine negative. Wenn [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mist_Dung_Duenger_Dreck_Sache) das nach Bedeutung sortiert hat, dann überwiegt sogar die positive, die Verwendbarkeit als Dünger.

Im [Meyer von 1885](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Mist&werk=Meyers) lautet der Eintrag sogar schlicht:

> **Mist** (Stallmist), s. Dünger, S. 219.

Das ist auch der Grund für die Misthaufen auf Bauernhöfen, die vor dem Aufkommen von Mineraldüngern unverzichtbar waren und ganz moderne **Nachhaltigkeit**.

Auch die Redensart

> das ist nicht auf jemandes Mist gewachsen

stellt eher den positiven Aspekt als Dünger in den Vordergrund.

Comment: Das ist zwar interessant zu wissen, aber es geht irgendwie an der Frage vorbei. Als Muttersprachler war mir z.B. die Redewendung auch kontextabhängig als negativ oder positiv bekannt, wäre aber nie auf die Idee gekommen, dass der "Mist" selber eine positive Bedeutung haben könnte. Ok, aber irgendwie enthält die Frage auch zwei Fragen in einem - die Wortherkunft erklärst du, das intuitive Verständnis durch Muttersprachler eher nicht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das *intuitive Verständnis durch Muttersprachler* - speziell beim Begriff "Mist" - dürfte heute ein grundlegend anderes sein als z.B. vor 200 Jahren, als Mist in gewissem Sinne eine Lebensgrundlage darstellte.

Comment: Ein großer Misthaufen ist bzw. war früher ein Zeichen für viel Vieh im Stall. Er ist/war also ein Indiz für Wohlstand.

Answer (score 5):

In Ergänzung zu @guidots Antwort und um auf die Nachfrage einzugehen:

Betonung und Kontext dürften auch eine Rolle spielen.

Ich erinnere mich tatsächlich noch an das erste Mal, als ich diese Redewendung im Zusammenhang mit einem kleinen Gewinn im Rahmen eines Brettspiels gehört habe. Wenn jemand etwas Geringes, z.B. einen niedrigen (Spiel-)Geldbetrag gewinnt, ergibt sich die positive Bedeutung zumindest für Muttersprachler m.E. eindeutig aus dem Kontext.

Zudem wird nicht *auch* oder *Mist*, sondern *Klein-*(vieh) betont. Daraus kann man schon schließen, dass es nicht um Mist vs. Gold (o.ä.) geht, sondern um Klein- vs. Großvieh, also dass sich die Redewendung auf die Menge des fraglichen Gegenstands bezieht. Anders wäre es sicherlich, wenn die Betonung auf *auch* oder *Mist* läge: Dann könnte man in der Tat denken, dass es darum ginge, dass Kleinvieh *nicht nur Freude*, sondern auch Mist macht. Aber eben nur dann.

Comment: Für mich wird das _auch_ ebenfalls betont, der Spruch ist wie von dir gesagt als Fortsetzung des Gedankens zu verstehen: "Großvieh macht (viel) Mist, aber ..." Richtig finde ich, dass '_Mist_' **nicht** betont werden darf, um den gemeinten Sinn zu treffen.

Answer (score 2):

Nachdem die anderen Antworten nur die im Titel gestellte Frage beantworten, will ich doch auch noch auf die am Ende des Eröffnungsposts gestellte eigentliche Frage des Threaderöffners eingehen:

> Wenn ein Muttersprachler zum ersten Mal diese Redewendung hört, hat er automatisch eine positive Konnotation? Oder sind da Kontext oder Vertrautheit notwendig?

## (Viele) Redewendungen müssen gelernt werden

In der Regel kann der Sinn einer späteren Redewendung bei deren erstem Gebrauch, z.B. in einem literarischen Werk, aus dem Kontext erschlossen werden, und manche idiomatischen Wendungen sind "sprechend" und erklären sich selbst. Bei den nicht bildhaften Wendungen aber gerät der Kontext des Erstauftretens mit der Zeit in Vergessenheit, und da sie sich nicht selbst erklären, muss ihre Bedeutung gelernt werden.

Ein Beispiel für eine "sprechende" Wendung ist, *wie ein Affe auf dem Schleifstein sitzen*. Damit ist genau das gemeint, was die Wendung beschreibt: eine seltsame, unbequeme und eventuell lächerliche Körperhaltung. Die Wertung kommt dann vom Kontext der Verwendung, aber die Bedeutung der Wendung ist klar, auch wenn man sie zum ersten Mal hört.

Ein Beispiel für eine nicht sprechende Wendung ist *dem Affen Zucker geben*. Es bedeutet wohl so etwas wie "ausgelassen sein, überdreht sein". Das kann man aus der wörtlichen Bedeutung der Wendung nicht ohne weiteres erschließen und muss es lernen.

Ich begegne immer wieder Redewendungen, deren Bedeutung ich nicht kenne, und man kann auch an Kindern immer wieder beobachten, dass sie den Sinn vieler idiomatischer Wendungen, die einem selbst geläufig sind, anfänglich nicht verstehen und sie falsch verwenden. Wer mag, kann ja mal die [Liste deutscher Redewendungen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Redewendungen) durchsehen und schauen, ob er jede richtig versteht. Ich sicher nicht, obwohl ich ein, wie ich meine, gebildeter Muttersprachler bin.

Comment: Wenn man erstens sorgfältig hinhört und zweitens nicht nur die erstbeste Erklärung gelten lässt und drittens über die Bedeutung nachdenkt, kann man zumindest - auch als Kind - drauf kommen, dass eine zuerst angenommene Bedeutung nicht richtig sein kann. Vielleicht braucht man dafür ein gewisses sprachdetektivisches Gespür. Als nicht-muttersprachlicher Französisch-Lerner war es mir ab einem gewissen Level möglich, idiomatische Elemente in Texten zu identifizieren. Der kürzeste Weg war dann - okay -, in einem Wörterbuch die Übersetzung = 'Bedeutung' zu suchen und das dann so zu lernen.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Ja, identifizieren kann man Redewendungen in der Regel leicht. Nur verstehen kann man viele von ihnen allein aus dem Kontext der Verwendung nicht.

Answer (score 0):

Ich glaube, Redewendungen sind immer nur für bestimmte soziale Gruppen sofort verständlich. Für einen Bauern wäre das (manchmal leicht ironische) "Kleinvieh macht auch Mist" sofort verständlich, weil für ihn Mist als Dünger positiv besetzt ist und daher ihm der Sinn durchaus klar wird. Andere Gruppen dagegen könnten Mist eher negativ sehen (= Dreck) und deshalb die eigentliche Bedeutung keineswegs sofort erschließen können.

Comment: Wenn man bedenkt, dass vor der Industrialisierung 80% der Bevölkerung in der Landwirtschaft tätig waren (heute sind es noch 1,6%), kann man nachvollziehen, das damals wohl die Mehrheit "Mist" als positiv verstanden hat und die direkte Bedeutung heute nicht mehr jedem ganz so klar ist.